# Routing in Phalcon - parameter before the end of the route

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm trying to set up routing in Phalcon, following this URL structure:

> www.example.com/language/register/

This is my `routes.php`:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Router;

$router = new Router();

$router->add(
    '/[a-z]{2}/register/',
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'register',
        'lang' => 1
    )
);

return $router;
```

And this is my IndexController:

```
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
    public $lang;

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function registerAction($lang)
    {
        $lang = $this->dispatcher->getParam('lang');
        echo "Register ($lang)"; //test
    }

}
```

Therefore, if I was to visit `www.example.com/fr/register/` it would take me to the `index` controller, the `register` action, with the lang parameter `fr`.

However, it is not displaying the `$lang` variable on the page.

I can see in the [Phalcon documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html) that you cannot use the `/:params` placeholder anywhere but at the end of the route (URL), but this is a regular expression being named within the router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it right, you just forgot your brackets around `[a-z]{2}`

```
$router->add(
    '/([a-z]{2})/register/', // added brackets here
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'register',
        'lang' => 1
    )
);
```

Now you can access your `lang` via

```
$lang = $this->dispatcher->getParam('lang');
```

Comment: Here is a shorter version in addition to Timothy's answer: `$router->add('/{lang:[a-z]{2}}/register', 'Index::register');`

Comment: @NikiMihaylov, I prefer the short version too! But sometimes it's less readable.